# Is possible to remove from a packaged helm chart one template and repackage it again?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, sprig-template-functions

I need to maintain a number of helm charts, and for some of them, I need 2 versions, with the only different of not adding some templates, the ones with a given annotation in this case.

I know I can wrap that template with `{{- if .Values.hasAnnotation }}` and then deploy passing true or false for hasAnnotation, but what I need is to create two packaged versions of the char and I want to void remove the template manually.

If there isn't a command for help me with this, my plan B is to create a GoLang tool using [Sprig](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/) but I'd prefer to avoid to deal with that

Open to any idea!

Comment: Are you thinking of template functions (`{{ define ... }}`) or whole template files (`templates/*.tpl`)?  These are, on some level, actual code, and you'd be doing things like checking one specific version of them into source control.  The `if` statement you describe seems like a better solution than trying to maintain two branches of the chart.

Comment: I have already segregated the resources, I need to remove the full `yaml` file from the packaged version, so as you said @DavidMaze, I need to modify the actual code.